# How to display nearby places like ATM's, hospitals in Android Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

How to display nearby places & place details like ATM's, Hospitals, Restaurants, etc. in Android Google Map

**This is the link that I used:**

[Showing nearby places & place details using Google Places & Maps API](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-and-place-details-using-google-places-api-and-google-maps-android-api-v2/)

I'm able to fetch my current location but nearby places are not getting displayed. Neither am I getting any error in my `logcat`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can get places near by your location using [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1) and for use of Place Api see [this blog](http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html)

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks got it. Also, is there any way to get updates about location change? That means if I need to receive a message about location change, is there any tutorial for that???

Comment: yes of course use Location Listener. here is a nice tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: Is it possible to get the nearest place list of a particular lat-long from new Place API?

Answer (score 1):

Get places nearby your location using [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1). Know about [Location Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location) also filter data with [Place Type](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) where you found the place to search, Places service,  place autocomplete requests and deprecated types. [`Resource 1`](https://developers.arcgis.com/example-apps/nearby-android/) [`Resource 2`](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the [Google Current Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place) but the results were limited to a few results and i could not change the radius around the current location. To get many results and to adjust the area radius around the current users location use the [Places Search API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests).