# List of close places without using a map object on android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am making a android application that needs to check if the user is close to a place of interest e.g. movie theater. (Within 1 km)

However I do not need the user to see a map which I think is required to use the google places api. I have done some research but am not sure how to accomplish this on android. Any tips (including comments or relevant links would be appreciated)

Comment: I don't recall needing to display a map to get the results... https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search the result is a json, you can do what you want with it.
Example for nearby museum https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&type=museum&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: Apart from showing google maps how are you expecting user to show this data?

Answer (score 7):

to see the nearby sites,

1.- use `Nearby Search Requests` from google maps, [link here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

2.- Use phone coordinates, to get a list of movie theater near of the coords...

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&types=movie+theater&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

3.- compare the two coordinates, and do your magic, maybe get distance by that two points and show user the distance..

> Note: if you want a lot of special places, you will need to see
>   another way to do it. That's what I thought...  is, in your server
>   need to do a request by coords with a lot of nearest places,
>   (museum,movie theater, etc.), and save that because google charges you
>   when the server check in many times, when the user send the
>   coordenates you will have a list of nearest places, if not, consult a
>   list of best pleaces and save in your server and send to user,
>
> you will need to use a some calculate coordenates, like range, if user
>   is near of this coordenates that i have in database send that
>   information if not, do request to server to consult nearest places
>   (with your predefinite list)

***Sorry for my English.***

**Links for more information**
[Find Places Nearby in Google Maps using Google Places API–Android App](http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/)
[Places APIs and Related Products](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1)
[how to display nearby places like atm,hospitals in android google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855298/how-to-display-nearby-places-like-atm-hospitals-in-android-google-map)

Comment: This should work well. You can get the phone location by using a broadcast receiver on the GPS , and Volley to cast the request and parse the response.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for GeoFences. Have a look here for more details : https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this to get places, enter your own search query

```
searchString = getIntent().getStringExtra("search_key");
GetPlacesTask getPlacesTask = new GetPlacesTask();
String url = getResources().getString(R.string.near_by_search) +
            "location="+latitude+","+longitude+"&radius=1000&type=" +
            searchString +"&keyword="+ searchString +
            "&key="+ YOUR_API_KEY;
String[] stringArray = new String[]{url};
getPlacesTask.execute(stringArray);
```

GetPlacesTask

```
private class GetPlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Place>>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Place> doInBackground(String... strings)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler(url);
            String result = httpHandler.getURLResponse();
            ArrayList<Place> placesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONObject mainResponse;
            JSONArray jsonArray;
            mainResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            jsonArray = mainResponse.getJSONArray("results");
           if(jsonArray.length() > 0)
           {
               placesArrayList = fetch(jsonArray);
           }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return placesArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Place> placesArrayList)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(placesArrayList);

        if(!placesArrayList.isEmpty())
        {
            //Show Places in your views
        }
    }
}
```

HttpHandler class

```
 public class HttpHandler
{
private URL url;
public HttpHandler(URL url)
{
    this.url = url;
}

public String getURLResponse()
{
    String response = "";

    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamIntoString(is);
        Log.d("RESPONSE", response);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return response;
}

private String convertStreamIntoString(InputStream inputStream)
{
    String response = "";
    String line;
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        response = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
}
```

[Here is the repository for the same](https://github.com/DuDuPoo/PlaceParse)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Awareness Api for nearby places.
You just have to create GoogleApiClient Object as below-

```
GoogleApiClient  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Awareness.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();

 mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Then Call below method for nearby places.

```
private void detectNearbyPlaces() {
        if (!checkLocationPermission()) {
            return;
        }

        Awareness.SnapshotApi.getPlaces(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlacesResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull PlacesResult placesResult) {
                        Place place;
                        if (placesResult.getPlaceLikelihoods() != null) {
                            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : placesResult.getPlaceLikelihoods()) {
                                place = placeLikelihood.getPlace();
                                Log.e(TAG, place.getName().toString() + "\n" + place.getAddress().toString());
                                Log.e(TAG, "Rating: " + place.getRating());
                                Log.e(TAG, "Likelihood that the user is here: " + placeLikelihood.getLikelihood() * 100 + "%");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.